# Insert arbitrary number of elements into array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, array-splice

Suppose I have an array like this:

```
['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
```

And I wanted to insert 3 elements starting at position 2:

```
['foo', 'bar', null, null, null, 'baz']
```

I could use [`Array.prototype.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) like this:

```
['foo', 'bar', 'baz'].splice(2, 0, null, null, null);
```

However, I'm looking to **insert an arbitrary number of elements**, or for the purposes of what I'm doing, **repeating the previous element an arbitrary amount of times** is also fine. My desired result:

```
// When position = 2 and n = 3
['foo', 'bar', null, null, null, 'baz']

// Alternatively, repeat the element at position-1:
['foo', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'baz']
```

How would I do this? jQuery is acceptable but I'm not sure how it would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can propose a solution when `undefined` values are inserted rather than `null`:

```
var a = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
a.splice.apply(a, [2, 0].concat(Array(3)));
console.log(a); // ["foo", "bar", undefined, undefined, undefined, "baz"]
```

You can control number of items to be inserted with parameter passed into `Array` constructor.

Comment: I guess `undefined` will have to do for now.